# How to Get element of Iframe?

Tags: c#

i want to automate page using web browser automation.

In the there is only an iframe at runtime value comes to that iframe.

when i try get the value of i frame it returns only the iframe not whole page html,

I want to click a href of i frame.

Please help me to solve this problem I am code.

```
 HtmlDocument dd = (HtmlDocument)loginBrowser.Document.GetElementById("UIFrame");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
HtmlDocument.contentWindow.body
```

I have no idea of c# and what you are doing (I'm a PHP man mainly these days) but it looks to me like you are casting an IFrame element to a HTMLDocument type? This may be wrong, as the IFrame element is not identical with the `body`. Is that casting really necessary? Maybe cast it to a [HTMLElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.aspx) instead?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want

```
HtmlDocument.Body
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument_members.aspx

the Body is an 
`HtmlElement`, which has properties for the `InnerHtml` and `InnerText`, if you want to look for data returned in the IFrame document.

See the following for more on HtmlElement
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.aspx

Also, are you sure you want to be casting to `HtmlDocument`? Looking at MSDN, it looks like GetElementById() should return an HtmlElement.

Answer (score 0):

If jQuery is available in your target website then try this:

```
browser.Document.InvokeScript("eval", new object[] { "$(\"#iframe_id\").contents().find('#element').html())" });
```